# How did they prove $\frac{1}{2}P=Q=R$?

Tags: solution-verification, vectors, physics, classical-mechanics, statics

**Question:**

Three forces of magnitudes $P, Q$, and $R$ act along the three sides of an equilateral $\triangle ABC$. If their resultant passes through the centroid and is parallel to the side $BC$, prove that $\frac{1}{2}P=Q=R$.

**My book's attempt:**

[image]

[This is my book's figure, but it is unclear, so I drew a clearer picture.]

[image]

Let resultant=$R'$

$AB, BE$, and $CF$ are medians & $G$ is the centroid.

Let $AD=BE=CF=x$

Note that the medians are perpendicular to the opposite side.

Taking moment about point $B$,

$$Q\cdot BE=R'\cdot GD\tag{1}$$

$$Qx=R'\frac{x}{3}$$

$$Q=\frac{R'}{3}\tag{4}$$

Taking moment about point $A$,

$$P\cdot AD=R'\cdot AG\tag{2}$$

$$Px=R'\frac{2}{3}x$$

$$\frac{1}{2}P=\frac{R'}{3}\tag{5}$$

Taking moment about point $C$,

$$R\cdot CF=R'\cdot GD\tag{3}$$

$$Rx=R'\frac{x}{3}$$

$$R=\frac{R'}{3}\tag{6}$$

From $(4), (5)$ and $(6)$,

$$\frac{1}{2}P=Q=R\ \text{(Proved)}$$

**My comments:**

(See my book's figure for this) Why is the vector in the middle acting in two directions? Shouldn't $R'$ have one direction? In my figure, it is acting from $G$ to $S$ **and** from $G$ to $T$. Why is it acting in two directions? Were they not sure which is the right direction, so they just drew it in both directions? Moreover, how did they formulate $(1)$? What was the reasoning/intuition behind $(1)$? If I can understand $(1)$, I'll understand $(2)$ and $(3)$ as well. I think $(1)$ is wrong because, in $(1)$, the author is assuming that $P$ and $R$ have no moment about $A$. Only $Q$ has moment about $A$ according to the author, which I think is wrong.

**My questions:**

1. Why is the vector(s) in the middle acting in two directions?
2. What is the reasoning/intuition behind $(1)$?

Comment: There is contradiction in problem statement and solution. Problem statement contradiction: At such forces $P,Q,R$ directions as shown in picture resultant cannot be parallel to $BC$ because forces $R$ and $Q$ have uncompensated components in direction $DA$. Solution contradiction: Formulae (1) and (2) are written as $R'$ is directed left, and formula (3) is written as $R'$ is directed right. I believe there is wrong direction of force $R$ in the picture.

Comment: Corrected (B instead A) $R$ and $P$ have no moment around $B$ because the moment of force is product of force and distance from force action line to point around which moment is calculated. As action lines for forces $R$ and $P$ are going trough $B$ so these products are both equal to zero.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu If the direction of $R$ is opposite (from A to B) of what the direction is currently (B to A), will the direction of R be correct then?

Comment: If $R$ direction will be opposite, then there will be no contradiction in problem statement and solution. But the only correct $R'$ direction will be then left direction from $G$ to $T$.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu How will (3) look if $R'$ is directed left?

Comment: If $R$ is directed from A to B and $R'$ is directed left then (3) will look exactly like in question. If $R$ is directed from B to A and $R'$ is directed left then one need to add sign "-" in one of the sides, which makes (3) contradictory.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Just to be clear, if $R$ is directed from A to B, then are $(1)$, $(2)$, and $(3)$ correct, sir? In other words, if $R$ is directed from A to B and $R'$ is consequently directed from G to T, will the entire solution (that I wrote) be correct?

Comment: As I see, entire solution will be correct.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135364/discussion-between-tryingtobeastoic-and-ivan-kaznacheyeu).